# Angular best practice for sending hidden data fields

Tags: angularjs

I have a small angular app which has a form template for creating tasks, which have a parent project. Project instances are governed by routing and so the user doesn't input/ edit this data. Now, I still need to send the `project id` with the form to the backend.

**Template:**

```
<form name="newTaskForm">

  <input ng-model="new_task.title" type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required />
  <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="createTask(new_task)">create</a>

</form>
```

As far as I can tell there are at least 4 straight-forward methods of sending the `project id`.

**1. Use a hidden field in the template**

```
<form name="newTaskForm">

  <!-- HIDDEN -->
  <input ng-model="new_task.project" type="hidden" id="project" name="project" class="form-control" value="{{ project.id }}" />
  <!-- END HIDDEN -->

  <input ng-model="new_task.title" type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required />
  <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="createTask(new_task)">create</a>

</form>
```

**2. Initialize the `new_task` object with a project id in the template**

```
<form name="newTaskForm" ng-init="new_task.project = project.id">

  <input ng-model="new_task.title" type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required />
  <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="createTask(new_task)">create</a>

</form>
```

**3. Initialize the `new_task` object with a `project id` in the `controller`**

```
.controller('TaskCtrl', function ($scope, project) {
    $scope.project = project;
    $scope.new_task = {project: $scope.project.id}
    ...
});
```

**4. Add `project id` to `new_task` object before submitting**

```
.controller('TaskCtrl', function ($scope, project) {

    $scope.createTask = function(obj) {
        // add project id
        obj.project = $scope.project.id;
        // $http submission
        ...
   };
   ...
});
```

My question is - does it matter? Is there a preferred method of achieving this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 - may be with a little optimization: delegate the knowledge how to create a new task to a service.

Why?

- It doesn't matter what kind of ui you are using to create your tasks. You have always a valid task in your model.
- If you change your ui you can not forget to setup any hidden fields or the ng-init - because you don't need them.
- Because you have always a valid task you can not forget to make the tasks valid before you post them to the server.
- if your task are getting more complex you mus only change the controller (or the service if you decide to use one)
- You can test your code in unit tests without any ui or $http mocking.
- ...